# jQuery noConflict error using Ajax

Tags: jquery, web

I am having to use

```
var jQuery_1_11_3 = $.noConflict(true);
```

as a 3rd party widget is loading in another libary in to my site which was causing problems.

I am getting the error 'expected expression, got '.' which is relating to the code

```
    jQuery_1_11_3('#emailForm').submit(function() {
            $name = jQuery_1_11_3('#name').val();
            $email = jQuery_1_11_3('#email').val();
            $addressOne = jQuery_1_11_3('#addressOne').val();
            $addressTwo = jQuery_1_11_3('#addressTwo').val();
            $addressThree = jQuery_1_11_3('#addressThree').val();
            $addressFour = jQuery_1_11_3('#addressFour').val();
            $dob = jQuery_1_11_3('#dob').val();
            //$('#formMain').html('<img src="../images/common/loading.gif" class="contactFormLoader" />');
            .ajax({
                type: "post",
                url:  "/includes/passportform_handler.php",
                data: "name=" + $name + "&addressOne=" + $addressOne  + "&addressTwo=" + $addressTwo  + "&addressThree=" + $addressThree  + "&addressFour=" + $addressFour + "&email=" + $email + "&dob=" + $dob,
                success: function(resp){
                    //$('#formMain').fadeIn();                          
                    jQuery_1_11_3('#formMain').html(resp);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

I am assuming it is the .ajax call which is the problem, but not sure what should be used instead. Any help would be much apprecitated!

Comment: Syntax error. You have a line of code that starts ".ajax({..." which follows a semicolon on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the `noConflict`, that variable needs to be present anywhere you would previously have used `jQuery` or `$`.

So this line:

```
.ajax({
```

Should be this:

```
jQuery_1_11_3.ajax({
```

To reference your noConflict instance of jQuery.